# Sorting on nested attribute, Mongoid

Tags: mongoid

I have a model with this schema:

```
class Treatment
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :value, type: Money # money-rails gem
end
```

That value field get saved to the db as `value: {"cents"=>313, "currency_iso"=>"EUR"}`

I would like find all treatments and sort them by the `cents` value.

Right now this is how I do it:

`Treatment.collection.find().sort({value: { :cents => 1 }})`

This is using the Moped driver. How can I do this using plain Mongoid?

Edit1.

```
  [6] pry(main)> Treatment.all.only(:value).asc('value.cents').entries
  => [#<Treatment _id: 515854c2a1d24ccb1f000005, value: {"cents"=>2849, "currency_iso"=>"EUR"}>,
   #<Treatment _id: 515854c2a1d24ccb1f000006, value: {"cents"=>313, "currency_iso"=>"EUR"}>,
   #<Treatment _id: 515854c2a1d24ccb1f00000f, value: {"cents"=>1214, "currency_iso"=>"EUR"}>,
   #<Treatment _id: 515854c2a1d24ccb1f000010, value: {"cents"=>1795, "currency_iso"=>"EUR"}>,
   #<Treatment _id: 515854c2a1d24ccb1f000011, value: {"cents"=>105, "currency_iso"=>"EUR"}>,
   #<Treatment _id: 515854c2a1d24ccb1f000012, value: {"cents"=>2547, "currency_iso"=>"EUR"}>
```

Edit2.

mongodb: stable 2.4.1-x86_64
mongoid (3.1.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dot syntax:

```
Treatment.all.asc('value.cents')
```

**edit:**
Full example:

```
require 'mongoid'
Mongoid.load!("mongoid.yml", :development)

class Treatment
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :value, type: Hash
end

Treatment.delete_all

15.times do
  Treatment.create(value: {cents: rand(3000), currency_iso: "EUR" })
end
p Treatment.all.only(:value).asc('value.cents').map{|t| t.value["cents"] }
```

Comment: That was my first thought. But it just doesn't work. The entries are not ordered.

Comment: Which version of mongoid/mongodb are you using? I posted a full example that's working for me using Mongoid 3.1.2 and MongoDB 2.2.0.

Comment: I think the key here is that I am using the money-rails gem

Comment: I tried changing the Money field to a Hash; Then I did you query, and I still get the results unordered.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out if ideas then. It works perfectly here and money-rails just [converts the object into a `Hash`](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails/blob/master/lib/money-rails/mongoid/money.rb#L4) upon serialization.

Comment: lol, there was a default_scope asc(:name) messing with the query.